# Getting Column Name and another column value if column has null in rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark data frame with id and few more columns. Id can never be null, however other columns may have null in it. Input Data Frame is

```
|A|    |id| |b|
|1|     |1|     |2|
|null|  |2|     |3|
|null|  |3|     |null|
```

I want to capture all the columns where we have null and corresponding id  and appending columns one below the another.
Expected output

```
|colName|   |id|
|A|     |2| 
|A|     |3|
|B|     |3|
```

Thanks in advance. Please try avoiding some manual loops.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below approach,
Please suggest in case any changes required.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
//sample RDD
val rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(1,1,2),Row(2,null,3),Row(3,null,null)))
//schema
val schema=(new StructType).add("ID",IntegerType).add("A",IntegerType).add("B",IntegerType)
//creating dataframe
var df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
df.show
+---+----+----+
| ID|   A|   B|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   1|   2|
|  2|null|   3|
|  3|null|null|
+---+----+----+

//get all the columns except ID column
val columnsExceptID=df.columns.filter(_!="ID")
//fill the corresponding column name in the place of null
df=columnsExceptID.foldLeft(df){(df,column)=>df.withColumn(column,when(col(column).isNull,column).otherwise(""))}

//array + explode ---> to get required output pattern of DF      
df=df.withColumn("colName",array(columnsExceptID.map(col(_)):_*)).drop(columnsExceptID:_*)

df=df.select('ID,explode('colName)).where(length('col)>0)
df.show
+---+---+
| ID|col|
+---+---+
|  2|  A|
|  3|  A|
|  3|  B|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Don't just do tail, filter it out explicitly. I.e. df.columns.filter(_ != "ID")